# Where does Gparted store that information such as Flags for those Partitions?

Tags: partition

From what I have gathered when it comes to information but, correct me if I'm wrong. Gparted and Programs like it store information regarding to Partitions on the drive. Gparted stores all that information into a file that is invisible and placed in a area that is unaccessible and from then on that's where the Partitions goes. That's the reason why when you mount a Drive, it states 15.6 GB, on the box it states 16 GB. The 0.4 GB is the space where the invisible file goes.

Comment: Yes but not a hidden file. It is just hidden-ish data. A file system has to store file-names, directories, permissions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be thinking of is reserved space when you use gparted to create a EXT4 filesystem. Gparted will use %5 of the drive for reserved space as specified in the man pages for tune2fs(8) when creating a EXT4 filesystem:

> -m reserved-blocks-percentage
>
> Set the percentage of the filesystem which may only be allocated by privileged processes. Reserving some number of filesystem blocks for use by privileged processes is done to avoid filesystem fragmentation, and to allow system daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to function correctly after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the filesystem. Normally, the default percentage of reserved blocks is 5%.

You can confirm if this is the case with tune2fs program:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/partition  | grep 'Reserved'
```

where `/dev/partition/` is your partition, e.g `sda1`

You can avoid this by creating a partition manually:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 /dev/sda1
```

---

PS, your title differs from your actual question. Please be more specific by editing your question if this is wasn't the answer you were looking for.